# Work done in bringing a sphere to a charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy

In page-87 of Purcell, David J. Morin Electricity and magnetism (3 ed) , the following theorem is discussed:

> Theorem 2.1 If $\phi(x, y, z)$ satisfies Laplace’s equation, then the average value of $\phi$ over the surface of any sphere (not necessarily a small sphere) is equal to the value of $\phi$ at the centre of the sphere.

The proof starts with bringing charge ($q'$) from infinity to a sphere(of charge $q$) which was easy for me to understand, the second part involves bringing the sphere to the charge which I find difficult to understand. I quote the second part:

> Now suppose, instead, that the point charge $q$ was there first and the
> charged sphere was later brought in from infinity. The work required for that is the product of $ q′$ and the average over the surface $S$ of the potential due to the point charge $q$. Now the work is surely the same in the second case, namely $\frac{qq′}{4π\epsilon_0R}$, so the average over the sphere of the potential due to $q$ must be $\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_o r}$. That is indeed the potential at the centre of the sphere due to the external point charge $q$.

I have two main questions on the above paragraph:

1. What exactly does it mean to average a function over a surface?
2. Why should the work be the product of the charge $q'$ with the average potential?

Answer (score 1):

1. To average a function $f(\mathbf r)$ over a sphere means to integrate the value of the function over the sphere and divide by the area of the sphere.
   $$\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\int_{\rm sphere}f(\mathbf r)\,dS.$$
   This is the usual way to define averages.
2. If we bring a point charge $q'$ to a point in space where there is a potential $V(\mathbf r)$ created by other charges, then the work needed is $q'V(\mathbf r)$. If, as in your case, the charge that we bring is not a point charge, but is distributed over a sphere of radius $R$, we need to sum (integrate) the work done to bring each infinitesimal charge at each point in the sphere $dq=\sigma dS$ multiplied by the potential at that point in the sphere:
   $$W=\int_{\rm sphere} V(\mathbf r)dq=\int_{\rm sphere} \sigma V(\mathbf r) dS.$$
   Since the total charge in the sphere is $q'$, then $\sigma=q'/(4\pi R^2)$, so that the work needed is
   $$\int_{\rm sphere} \sigma V(\mathbf r) dS=q'\underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\int_{\rm sphere} V(\mathbf r) dS\right]}_{\text{average of V over the sphere}}.$$

Comment: The integral looks kinda sketch because as you bring in more and more charge, then the charges on sphere would cause a work of it's own. So the total work would have to include that as well (not just the work against pushing charge w.r.t the fixed charge which is kept originally)

Comment: Basically, how are you accounting for the changing charge density ?